# Imports, actualizarlos en el output. Esbuild

Tags: reactjs, sass, esbuild

¡Hola!, ante nada quiero desearles un lindo día, tarde o noche, espero se encuentren bien.

Estoy creando un componente de [React](https://react.dev), el cual pienso subir a NPM para reutilizar en futuros proyectos. Para transpilar mi código estoy usando [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io), y es con [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io) mi problema.

Estoy usando sass en mi proyecto, por lo tanto estoy usando [esbuild-sass-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-plugin-auto-css-modules) junto a [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io), el problema no radica en la [transpilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpilador) de los archivos, sino en que los archivos de salida [.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript) siguen incluyendo las importaciones de sass y no se actualizan a css.
Dejo un ejemplo a continuación.
***input.tsx***

```
import 'file.sass'
```

***output.js***

```js
import 'file.sass' //Quiero que esto cambie a *import 'file.css'*
```

Lo ideal sería para mi que al [transpilar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpilador) los imports pasaran de ***[.css](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS)*** a ***[.sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide/)***

Actualmente en mis [tsx](https://react.dev) estoy importando los ***[.sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide/)*** como ***[.css](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS)***, esto me va bien pero al momento de realizar test con jest, jest me da un error al no poder encontrar el archivo ya que se indica ***[.css](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS)*** y son ***[.sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide/)***, además no creo que hacer eso sea una buena practica.

¡Espero su ayuda y gracias de antemano!

***esbuild.config.mjs***

```
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild'
import { sassPlugin } from 'esbuild-sass-plugin'

const ctx = await esbuild.context({
    entryPoints: ['src/**/*.tsx', 'src/**/*.sass'],
    bundle: false,
    outdir: 'dist',
    platform: 'browser',
    sourcemap: 'external',
    resolveExtensions: ['.css','.sass'],
    plugins: [
        sassPlugin(),
    ],
})

console.log('Building! ⚡')
await ctx.watch()
```